# Foreach , and get a name by ID return nothing

Tags: php, html

So , i'm going to post more code ton explain my problem :

```
class Projects{
private $project_id;
private $project_name;
private $project_state;

public function SetAllProject($id_projcet,$name_projcet,$state_project){
 $this->project_id= $id_projcet;
 $this->project_name= $name_projcet;
 $this->project_state= $state_project;
}
```

In my index page of my website , I get all project and I store like this :

```
while($dataProjet = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
$ObjProjet->SetAllProject($dataProjet["project_id"],$dataProjet["project_name"],$dataProjet["project_state"]);
$arrObjProject[$i] = $ObjProject; 
$i++;
```

and my goal is to get a name of a project with his ID . With:

```
public function getProjetNameByID($p_id){
     foreach($this->project_id as $idproj)
     {
         if($idproj == $p_id){
             return $this->project_name;
         }

    }
    return null;
}
```

But it always return null...
Thanks for helping !

Comment: `$this->project_id` : is that a collection (array/list) ?

Comment: I believe he will need to change `foreach($this->project_id as $idproj)` for `foreach($this->project_id as $index => $value)` since he wants to access what i assume is the corresponding value at the same index in `$this->project_name`

Comment: @cid, no is a var from a class , and Xoxel i'm going to test :) Thanks

Comment: @CodingLyon if it's not an array, then you can't foreach it.

Comment: Watchout there is still a need to change a few things in your code, what i wrote is not pure magic code, it will need you to use $index as an index, and value as you was using id_proj, also we need to know precisely what are project_id and project_name, i mean, are they arrays ? of what ? Objects ?

Comment: Yep and as @Cid said:  foreach works only with arrays and list as it's an iterator, and well, you can"t really iterate on a single value

Comment: @Cid and myself both updated our answers, consider leaving an upvote if it's working :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering what you said in comments, you're trying to loop over a simple variable that isn't possible.

You've built an array of projects objects from the database, that's what you have to iterate.

```
function getProjetNameByID($p_id, $ArrayOfProjects) {
    foreach($ArrayOfProjects as $ObjProject)
     {
         if($ObjProject->project_id == $p_id)
             return $ObjProject->project_name;
    }
    return null;
}

$nameofproject = getProjetNameByID(1, $arrObjProject);
echo "The name of the project is : $nameofproject";
```

Comment: (you made a little mystake, it's not this-> project_name anymore, change the this for ObjProject ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Your else condition is wrong. You will check the first `if` statement, if it's wrong then you'll get into the `else` and this will `return null`, kicking you out, this is how you could return null if nothing is found in your foreach:

```
 public function getProjetNameByID($p_id){
     foreach($this->project_id as $idproj)
     {
         if($idproj == $p_id){
             return $this->project_name;
         }

    }
    return null;
}
```

As suggested by @Cid a solution to your second problem would be to use your array of projects since you already have one, this way:

```
 public function getProjetNameByID($p_id){
     foreach($arrObjProject as $proj)
     {
         if($proj->project_id == $p_id){
             return $proj->project_name;
         }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for you help , but I do not see one error : "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " ... And return null again :(

Comment: We will need more code in order to determine where this error come from precisely, but i'am pretty sure it comes from this line: `return $this->project_name;` , Since the begining you wasn't even entering here i suppose (could also be the foreach declaration if the argument you pass is not suitable), as the if statement was checked only for the first element (and it ended up being false so you got trapped into your else wich kicked you out fo the loop, etc, i explained it). What are project_id and project_name ? @CodingLyon

Comment: So , i'm doing a project follow , to know the state of one project , i'm going to store all projects from by sql database , in objects .. And project_id and project_name are var from my class

Comment: So I have posted an answer to explain more ;)